# Mass insert data at end of MySQL field

Tags: mysql, database, html

How would I go about mass inserting an ending `</div>` tag into a defined field name in MySQL?

Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the CONCAT command:

```
UPDATE jos_content SET fulltext = CONCAT( fulltext, '</div>' ) WHERE id = 7;
```

If you wanted to update ALL your records in a single query, simply remove the WHERE clause above.

Please note, depending on what server side language you're using, you'll want to setup a parameterized query for this to prevent SQL injection or other hacks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have very limited knowledge of MySQL and programming in general. Would you please be able to give me more detailed instructions? Can you use my specific example where the table name is `jos_content` and the field name is `fulltext`? @Dillie-O

Comment: @user2105885 I've gone ahead and updated the code snippet. Exactly how you implement this will depend on which backend language you are using (PHP, .Net, Ruby on Rails, etc.) Please make sure to do some research into parameterized queries to secure your update.

Comment: Thanks heaps. I got this working. However i have encountered another problem. Because i wasn't able to use the id attribute as i have thousands of different ids, this code affected every single table in my jos_content table, as expected. Can you tell me if there a way to delete `</div>` from any 'fulltext' field that contains only a single `</div>` and nothing else in that field? And then everything will be sorted. @Dillie-O

Comment: Alternatively can i use your initial code but employ the WHERE attribute to target any 'fulltext' field that has existing text in it and NOT target those 'fulltext' fields which have no existing data? @Dillie-O

Comment: Hi. I worked out that the catID was consistent across the fields i wanted to target. Thanks heaps for your help and your code. @Dillie-O